# dbt: How to handle convergent models?

Tags: dbt

*N.B. This is a repost of https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/discussions/7705, since it's not getting any response on the repo discussions.*

### Problem

We would like to have assistance with regard on how to structure our dbt models given our data model structure (convergent proprietary models into a standardized data model).

**Given the following data model:**

- Multitenant model where each tenant has a separate BigQuery dataset in which their respective data is loaded, then transformed.
- We integrate multiple competing providers that cover the same domain entities with different table structures; for each category of competing providers, a tenant will have data from only one of the competing providers.

For example, here's a simplified/genralized representation of a subset of the analytics DAG for two tenants respectively using different competing providers:

```
Tenant A (Provider P1):

P1.schedule --> std_schedule
P1.order --> std_order
P1.order_item --> std_order

Tenant B (Provider P2):

P2.t_schtemp --> std_schedule
P2.t_billinvoice --> std_order
P2.t_billitem --> std_order
```

**Then how can we structure our dbt project to dynamically switch between providers?**

### Proposed solution

Our current (incomplete) understanding of how to support multiple concurrent implementation of a given model (e.g. std_schedule, std_order) is the following:

1. One dbt execution per tenant (given they have different impl & schema)
2. Tag sources (`P1.*`, `P2.*`) with the provider identifier (e.g. `acme_provider`, `corp_provider`)
3. Have a single model file for a standardized (common) model (e.g. std_schedule, std_order)
4. Split each provider custom implementations into separate SQL files to be included using jinja's `include`
5. Implement the standard models as switches between implementation using the passed tags

Would that work?

- Does dbt support jinja's include? / Should the includes be marked as excluded in the dbt project?
- Would dbt be able to correctly write a manifest when tags are passed?
- Would dbt be able to correctly interpret the jinja2 SQL given the appropriate tags?
- How would this work if we wanted to integrate with dbt Cloud?

Alternatively, if you have a better model to propose, we are all ears!

Thanks so much for your answer